# antlr3StringStreamNew string input error [ at offset 0, at <EOF> : cannot match to any predicted input... ]

Tags: antlr3

I'm using ANTLR 3.4 with simplecTreeParser example and want to give string input from main.c

I'v modified input in main as mentioned bellow

```
pANTLR3_UINT8 input_string = (pANTLR3_UINT8)"int a;";

input = antlr3StringStreamNew(input_string, ANTLR3_ENC_8BIT, sizeof(input_string),(pANTLR3_UINT8)"ABCD");
```

Apparently getting following error

> -end of input-(1)  : error 3 : 23:1: declaration : ( variable | functionHeader ';' -> ^( FUNC_DECL functionHeader ) | functionHeader block -> ^( FUNC_DEF functionHeader block ) );, at offset 0, at  : cannot match to any predicted input...
>   The parser returned 1 errors, tree walking aborted.

Any other way to give String input

Regards

Answer (score 1):

```
pANTLR3_UINT8 input_string = (pANTLR3_UINT8)"int a;";

input = antlr3StringStreamNew(input_string, ANTLR3_ENC_8BIT, strlen(input_string),(pANTLR3_UINT8)"ABCD");
```

Use `strlen` insted of `sizeof`; that solved my problem.